# B1 rejected, likely because I failed to show evidence that I had collected! Should I immediately reapply again?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My B1 (from India) got rejected likely because I was operating on bad advice (and very nervous) and was exceedingly terse with my responses with the consular officer. Since he didn't explicitly ask for it, I failed to show my invite letter from the client, failed to show that I had a lease in Bangalore for 1 bedroom of a 3-bedroom flat apartment that had 8 months left, failed to show that I have strong ties with family and that I travel back to Delhi from Blr for around 4-5 weeks every 3 months. Additionally, while the information might have been with them, I also failed to showcase that I earn well above avg., and that my father also had a B1 that he'd used to attend business trips in the US.

I'm honestly thinking of just reapplying again immediately, despite the fact that there has been no material change in my conditions, only that I'd failed to showcase said condition!

Comment: What exactly were you asked and how did you answer? It might help you to read this https://de.usembassy.gov/interview-and-supporting-documents/

Comment: First couple of questions were about prior US stays. Which I've had with my family, as a kid. I'm pretty sure I should have been more expressive here, because the officer doubled back to this at the end when he asked whether my father was still in the US.

The Second lot of questions was about the purpose of visit and role. In this, I failed to adequately substantiate on my purpose or even intimate that I had an invitation letter and an itinerary, and I fumbled a bit on my role in the company. 

The final lot of questions was about my father and relatives in the US.

Comment: At this point, I really should have talked about my aprt, and that I came to Delhi frequently to stay for extended periods with my family, and the dog, but I just did not. In the end, I think I gave an impression of an unmarried 20-something wanting to go to the US for a vague business-related trip...

Comment: Well, now you have a refusal to overcome (and on your travel history), as well as a potential perception that a quick re-application means you’re desperate to get to the US. Unless you’re confident that you can perform better at the interview, personally I’d leave reapplying for a while rather than risk getting into a spiral of refusals.

Comment: That's a good point. A couple of more well-traveled friends have warned me of that, too. It's making me rethink the quick reapplication. That said, I should be getting an ITA from Canada within the next round or two of their lottery, so perhaps that would constitute material change.